# Answer by python language

Tags: python-3.x

A positive integer n is said to be perfect if the sum of the factors of n, other than n itself, add up to n. For instance 6 is perfect since the factors of 6 are {1,2,3,6} and 1+2+3=6. Likewise, 28 is perfect because the factors of 28 are {1,2,4,7,14,28} and 1+2+4+7+14=28.

Write a Python function perfect(n) that takes a positive integer argument and returns True if the integer is perfect, and False otherwise.

Here are some examples to show how your function should work.

> > > perfect(6)
> > >       True
> > >       perfect(12)
> > >       False
> > >       perfect(28)
> > >       True

Comment: This appears to be homework. While asking homework questions are O.K., please at least show that you have put some effort into first solving the problem before expecting someone else to solve it for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def perfect(x): 
    factor_sum = 0   
    for i in range(1, x-1):
        if x % i == 0:
            factor_sum = factor_sum + i
            if(factor_sum == x):
                return True
    return False

print perfect(6) #Prints True
print perfect(12) #Prints False
print perfect(28) #Prints True
```